ngx-clipboard does not fire a success event?
<button  *ngIf="func(rowData)"  ngxClipboard
              [cbContent]="fileFullName" (cbOnSuccess)="showSuccessDialog($event)" [axTooltip]="copyMsg"
              [title]="fileName">
            </button>

link is correctly copied but dialogService or the below func never gets executed
private showSuccessDialog(fileFullUrl: string): void {
    console.log("here")
    this.dialogService.showMessage('File link copied to clipboard!');
  }

angular 16 primeng16 ngx-clipboard v16
tried changing to $event, using the service but i just need a dialog box to show success.
